# parallelshell command not found

Tags: jenkins

When I run parallelshell command (I installed parallelshell using npm install -g parallelshell), on the server, it works. But when Jenkins runs the command, I get the error, `parallelshell command not found`.

Why is Jenkins not recognizing the command? the command works for me when I log into the server.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins may be running under different user(That is default in Windows service, or linux installations).  This will have different path variable and other user-specific settings.

You must give absolute path to command.